# windows search service is not working well

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, windows-services, search-indexing

first it was a driver index issue even when i click show all location, 
[driver cannot be found in indexed location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sg7m.png)
i tried to select new index location to be on the drive that was missing then the index service collapsed and did not run at all giving me an error when go to services and try running it manually:

```
Windows could not start the Windows Search service on Local Computer Error 21:  The device is not ready
```

and the select new location button grayed out, [select new button grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7GD.png)

then i delete the Key RebuildIndex and change value of key SetupCompletedSuccessfully to 1 in the registry edit as mention in one article, https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/36379-windows-search-indexing-broken.html and started to get another error when trying to run windows search service [Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTlx9.png)

any idea how to solve this issue?

windows details: windows 10 Home - version 1909 - OS build 18363.752

Comment: Turn off Indexing Service.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run both:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and sfc /scannow . When done, restart, turn on Index Service, restart again and rebuild the index.

Comment: i've tried it but no luck still the same problem

Comment: So then at this point, you may need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the download link, run in place, and try Keep Everything at the appropriate point. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: This repair will remove my apps and data?

Comment: If you use Keep Everything, nothing will be lost.

Comment: I would actually wait until `Windows 10 version 2004` is released, simply due to the Windows Search improvements, that will exist in that version.

Comment: Ok so because 20h1 update is soon i'll wait to see what will happen.

Comment: I have machines side by side with both versions  (1909 and 2004) . Search (indexing) is working equally well on both. No harm to wait and also no harm to repair what you have.

Comment: In the meanwhile you might try [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) by voidtools. IMO it is WAY more efficient than the Windows' own thing.